# How to push strings to array and print each of them in a newline?

Tags: arrays, perl, file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $sender;
my $receiver;
my @sender;
my @receiver;

open (FILE, "enron.csv");

while (<FILE>) {
    ($sender, $receiver) = split(/,/, $_);
    push @sender, $sender;
    push @receiver, $receiver;
}

print @sender;
print @receiver;
```

The file I am reading is email addresses: for each line, there is two addresses separated by comma. I want to store the addresses on the left and the right of the comma in two separate arrays.

The problem I am having is, when I print @sender, all addresses are linked together. There is no whitespace or newline in-between them.

For @receiver, everything works fine. Each address has its own line. (Newline at every end of address.)

How to fix @sender?

Thanks.

Comment: probably something like `print join "\n", @sender`

Comment: Do you know why I print sender and receiver in the same way however the format of result is different?

Comment: @NoahSong: Because receiver takes the "\n" from your input file whereas sender is not. Hence you need to add "\n" explicitly in your code for sender so that while printing you see results same as receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items in `@receiver` include the newlines from the input file. I'd start by removing that by calling `chomp` just inside your loop. Then, printing becomes

```
print map { "$_\n" } @sender;
print map { "$_\n" } @receiver;
```

or

```
print "$_\n" for @sender;
print "$_\n" for @receiver;
```

or

```
use feature qw( say );

say for @sender;
say for @receiver;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or else use List separator

```
$" = "\n";
print "@sender\n";
print "@receiver\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer.

I have to chomp for each of the receiver which already includes a newline with it.